# Парсинг с JSOUP. Как достать значения из Element?

Tags: android, html, jsoup, парсер

Я спарсил новостную страничку, используя библиотеку `JSOUP` и получил новость:

```
Element myNew...
Log.d("logs", "myNew-"+myNew.toString());
```

Логи показывают, что мой `Element` с новостью имеет следующий вид:

```
<div id="news-id-ХХХ" style="display:inline;">       
TEXT1   
<br>TEXT2   
<br>      
<div align="center">     
<img src="URL_IMAGE">
</div>    
<br>    
<br>TEXT3
</div>
```

Можно ли как-нибудь достать из этого `Element` значения TEXT_X так, чтобы сохранилась правильная последовательность элементов по порядку и получилось следующее:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>;
list.get(1) = "TEXT1";    
list.get(2) = "TEXT2";    
list.get(3) = "URL_IMAGE";    
list.get(4) = "TEXT3";
```

Как достать URL_IMAGE я разобрался, а вот с текстом беда выходит. Пытался достать текст методом `myNew.text()`, так программа берет весь TEXT из новости и получается следующее:

```
String s = TEXT1+TEXT2+TEXT3;
```

А мне текстовые значения нужно как-то разграничить, но я не понимаю как...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Только рекурсивным перебором нодов

```
static void extractContent(Node node, List<String> result) {
    if (node instanceof TextNode) {
        String text = ((TextNode) node).text().trim();
        if (!text.isEmpty()) result.add(text); // Добавляем только непустые тексты
    } else if ("img".equals(node.nodeName())) {
        result.add(node.attr("src"));
    } else {
        for (Node child : node.childNodes()) {
            extractContent(child, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
// Находишь нужный DIV в документе
Element div = doc.select("div#news-id-ХХХ").first();
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
extractContent(div, result);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Игорь, спасибо! Я проверю, но чуть позже.
Беда только в том, что когда я вчера пробовал доставать текст из нодов, у меня спец символы отображались примерно так "&nfpr". А Если я юзаю element.text(), то спец символны нормально отображаются...

Comment: Игорь, вы просто Батя с большой буквы в вопросах библиотеки JSOUP! Спасибо! Все работает офигенски и даже спецсимволы отображаются как нужно! Очень сильно выручили меня! Еще раз огромное спасибо!!! :)

Comment: Игорь, есть еще вопрос, наверное чисто теоретический.
Я видел в некоторых случаях, когда находят юзают метод doc.select(...), после приписывают строки типа windows 7, mozilla что-то в этом духе. Это принципиально вообще?